Investigate compilation font infos
Thanks to texlogsieve, I can investigate compilation messages.
I have the following message. How can I investigate this type of message?
pg 1: LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/it' in size <8> not available
      (Font)              Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/it' tried instead on input line 22.

The MWE used.
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\footnote{\textit{\texttt{\textbf{XXX}}}}

\end{document}


change your code so it doesn't try to select a non-existent font? how to change it depends on what the code is, of course, but you've not shared it.

note that this is defined as a silent substitution in the font definition file. this is information-level. it isn't a warning. so compilation-warning isn't accurate.

it works perfectly well. it is just information.

you've changed this question so the answers no longer apply to the message you show. please don't do this. it utterly confuses things, as you can see in the discussion between me and david below.

Your code requests Computer Modern monowidth typewriter bold extended italic in the EC encoding (T1). This isn't available, but the font definition for the CM monowidth typewriter family (t1cmtt.fd) provides a 'silent substitution' for this case. So there is no warning and certainly no error. LaTeX does, however, print an information-level message to the log telling you this has been done.
I don't know why you'd want to eliminate all such informational messages from the log. This kind of substitution is utterly common. However, if you really wish to eliminate them, ensure your code only asks LaTeX to load available fonts. This means the font exists as either a real or virtual font. You can check this in the font definition file for the family.
In this case, we find
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar \font\m@ne}
\EC@ttfamily{T1}{cmtt}{m}{n}{ectt}
\EC@ttfamily{T1}{cmtt}{m}{sl}{ecst}
\EC@ttfamily{T1}{cmtt}{m}{it}{ecit}
\EC@ttfamily{T1}{cmtt}{m}{sc}{ectc}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}%
  {<->ssub*cmtt/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{bx}{it}%
  {<->ssub*cmtt/m/it}{}

<->ssub tells us the specified font will be 'silently' substituted if the font shape being defined is requested. So,
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmtt}{bx}{it}%
  {<->ssub*cmtt/m/it}{}

explains why LaTeX substitutes the medium weight/regular width when you ask for bold extended.
As David explained, you can install additional CM fonts which provide (many of) the 'missing' fonts. However, installing cm-super will NOT eliminate the substitution or the message. Moreover, you are unlikely to find any font configuration which avoids such substitutions entirely unless you are extremely careful at the document level to avoid loading fonts requiring substitution. That would be a lot of effort for zero benefit, IMHO, but is naturally possible should you take a different view of the matter.
Addendum
Note that we do not get a warning for the bold italic case. Moreover, we get the same message regardless of whether cm-super is installed or not.
With David Carlisle's original example,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize\textit{\texttt{\textbf{abc}}}
\end{document}

we find the following in the log (with cm-super installed)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+cmtt on input line 4
.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd
File: t1cmtt.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/it' tried instead on input line 4.


[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/usr/loc
al/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}]

...

</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfit0800.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>

This is quite different from the slanted case. If we change \textit to \textsl as in in David's example,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize\textsl{\texttt{\textbf{abc}}}
\end{document}

we get a warning.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+cmtt on input line 4
.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd
File: t1cmtt.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmtt/bx/n' instead on input line 4.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/n' tried instead on input line 4.

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/usr/loc
al/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}]

Note the message is now not LaTeX Font Info but LaTeX Font Warning. Still not an error, but sufficiently important to get written to the console and the log. Moreover, LaTeX now outputs an additional message at the end of the run telling us some shapes were substituted.
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

Again, this happens regardless of whether cm-super is installed or not.
You can change what gets written to the console. For example, you could alter the threshold so only errors are written (not warnings) or so that more information is written (in addition to warnings and errors). By default, though, you will see complaints about missing fonts for the oblique (sl) case, but not the italic (it) case because LaTeX prints only messages of level warning or higher to the console by default, but additionally includes some lower level messages in the log.
If you want to see additional information or have trouble diagnosing font issues, loading the tracefnt.sty with or without the debugshow option may be helpful as it enables you to use lower level tracing commands to get information about what NFSS (LaTeX's font selection mechanism) is doing.

Thank you very much for this clarification.

@projetmbc please see edited answer!

Thanks "twice".
